# Grails 3.2.7 test url mappings with http method

Tags: unit-testing, grails, url-mapping

In Grails I have UrlMappings as follows:

```
static mappings = {
    '/route'(controller: 'route') {
        action = [POST: 'save', GET: 'index']
    }
}
```

I wanted to write unit tests for those mappings, however I cannot find in [documentation](http://docs.grails.org/3.2.7/guide/single.html#unitTestingURLMappings) how to use Http method  url mapping test.

I have tried adding method parameter to the assertions, but it does not work

```
assertUrlMapping([controller: 'route', action: 'index', method: 'GET'], '/route')
assertUrlMapping([controller: 'route', action: 'save', method: 'POST'], '/route')
```

Is there any way to do this?

EDIT:

The second one of the tests above fails with `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Url mapping action assertion for '/route' failed expected:<[save]> but was:<[index]>` message.

The main problem is that `assertUrlMapping` seems to work only for GET requests.

I have experimented with it by changing my mappings to:

```
static mappings = {
    '/route'(controller: 'route') {
        action = [POST: 'createRoute', PUT: 'updateRoute']
    }
}
```

and the tests to:

```
assertUrlMapping([controller: 'route', action: 'updateRoute', method: 'PUT'], '/route')
assertUrlMapping([controller: 'route', action: 'createRoute', method: 'POST'], '/route')
```

This failed with the following messages:

```
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Url mapping action assertion for '/route' failed expected:<[updateRoute]> but was:<[index]>
junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Url mapping action assertion for '/route' failed expected:<[createRoute]> but was:<[index]>
```

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean?

Comment: The second test fails with `junit.framework.ComparisonFailure: Url mapping action assertion for '/route' failed expected:<[save]> but was:<[index]>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try amending your test to specify the http method in the request. Something like this (using Spock):

```
def "test url mappings" () {
    when:
        request.method = "GET"
        assertUrlMapping("/route", controller: "route", action: "index", method: "GET")
    then:
        noExceptionThrown()        
    when:
        request.method = "POST"
        assertUrlMapping("/route", controller: "route", action: "save", method: "POST")
    then:
        noExceptionThrown()
}
```

I also struggled with this issue. I found this solution in the [source code for a grails test suite](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/blob/master/grails-test-suite-uber/src/test/groovy/grails/test/mixin/UrlMappingsTestMixinTests.groovy#L268).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a lot!